# Avoid refresh current page while it's loading when clicking a link

Tags: html

I think i am going crazy with this... there should be something that i am missing.

I have a html page that prints a lot of links in sequences... like this:

```
<a href="http://link1" target="_blank">link1</a>
<a href="http://link2" target="_blank">link2</a>
<a href="http://link3" target="_blank">link3</a>
...
```

The issue is that for some strange reasons when i click a link, the current page refresh while it's loading the content... and it's terribile because It needs to reload again all the links...

I have tried also this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://link1','_blank');">link1</a>
```

but still whenever I click the current page it refreshes (while it is still loading) starting again from zero

I am using chrome latest version on win 10

Any clues? What else could i do to avoid refreshing the current page ?

The only woraround i found is to intercept the closing with the message box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use preventDefault() method

```js
function openBlankPage(event,href) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('Opening the link')
   window.open(href,'_blank');
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <a href="#" onclick="openBlankPage(event,'https://www.google.hu/?gws_rd=ssl');">
    Go to google.com not refresh</a>

    <p>The preventDefault() method will prevent the link above from following the URL.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i want the link to follow the real link, just to open a new tab and not refresh the current page

Comment: Okey than simple comment the line `location.reload();` and then use only `event.preventDefault();` this will not refreshing the page

Comment: tried with preventDefault, it still refreshes the page... I don't know how to investiage who is causing this, because i think this is not the standard behaviour. Please note that my page when i click the link is still loading all the content since it's a very long content

Comment: To cancel page loading you can add `window.stop();`. I'm sorry I don't know exactly what you want to do, if you give more information ...